# Withings API disconnect/revoke token

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, withings, revoke-token

I'm getting Withings data into my android app, and I want that when the user clicks on a disconnect button the Withings account gets disconnected. But there is no URL to call to disconnect or revoke token in Withings API. So now the user stays connected all the time cause the user cookies are saved in the browser.

Is there any way to do that? with oAut2.0 or any other method?